# UEFI Shell hardcoded paths

Tags: shell, uefi

How Do I link paths to hardware instead of using `fsX:` inside UEFI Shell?

Context:

I am installing a new SSD on an older machine as the system disk. I am pretty much done. My solution involves loading NvmExpressDxe.efi and booting to the new ssd. However right now all paths are hardcoded and I assume that if I plug in another drive everything might break.

Inside startup.nsh there are lines like `load fs1:\efi\boot\NvmExpressDxe.efi` and `fs3:\efi\boot\bootx64.efi`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an OK solution...

In UEFI Shell (at least in my version) `map` command also displays aliases. For example something like: `fsX - Aliases hdXXXXXXXX blkX`.

So replacing `fsX` with `hdXXXXXXXX` works and is no longer pseudo-random, but it is still dependant on the exact port (that the device is connected to).

If anyone knows of an even better solution (that relies only on the exact hardware piece) I will be glad if you post it here.